# Custom Taxonomy Archive Page for Parents AND Children?

Tags: custom-taxonomy, archives

I have a custom taxonomy called Product Category, which has a range of parent categories, then each parent one has subsequent child categories.

Is it possible for the archive page i/e taxonomy-product-category.php to drill down in order of categories, not just go direct to the final posts?

Currently it lists the parent categories, clicking on a parent cat takes you to a list of posts only from the child categories NOT a list of the child categories like it should?

So i assume is there a conditional which you can put on the taxonomy-product-category.php if tax parent category show this, else show parent child categories?

Unsure if its possible dynamically.

I've tried the following but no luck..

```
<?php
$term = get_term_by('slug', get_query_var('term'), 'product-category'); if((int)$term->parent)

get_template_part('product','parent');

else

get_template_part('product','child');

?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`get_queried_object`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_queried_object) to return the full queried term object on a taxonomy archive page.

```
$term = get_queried_object();
if( 0 === $term->parent ){
    // term is top level
} else {
    // term has parent
}
```